# why is my file type validation invalid?

Tags: javascript

When I choose a file and click the submit button, it still pop up an alert to select a file.

How do I solve this?

```
function _validate() {
    var validate = true;
    if (FileAttachment === "") {
        validationMsgs("Select a file", "Validation", "Okay");
        validate = false;
    }
    return validate;
}
```

Comment: What does FileAttachment contain?

Comment: need more elaboration like when is the _validate being triggered and like @moon asked, what is fileattachment?

Comment: Please give more explanation. It is not clear.